# Разделить woocommerce_checkout_order_review на части WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На странице заказа есть колонки: Предпросмотр заказа, Варианты оплаты. Мне нужно колонку Предпросмотр заказа переместить в другое место шаблона.
Шаблоны каждой колонки нашел отдельно, в шаблоне сайта они вызываются одной функцией `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>`
Как их можно разделить?
К примеру, чтобы одну часть можно было вставить с помощью `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_review' ); ?>`, а другую `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' ); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно удалить привязку одного из вызовов

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

и назначить вызов к другому хуку

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 20 );
```

и обернуть это к вызову init

```
add_action('init', function(){
        
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 20 );

});
```

Визульный гайд по хука страницы чекаут

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/